# geom_contour() error after projecting WGS84 coordinates to UTM

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, terra

I have bathymetry data (in WGS84 Lat/Long) that I want to plot as contours using `ggplot`. I need my bathymetry contours in UTM. I can get contours when using the Lat/Long coordinates, but not when using the projected UTM coordinates.

```
require(marmap)
bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -156.4 , lon2 = -156.95, lat1 = 20.55, lat2 = 21.05 , resolution = 1)
bathy.df<-fortify(bathy)
bathy.df<-cbind(bathy.df,
 as.data.frame(terra::project(as.matrix(bathy.df[,c(1,2)]), "+proj=longlat", 
"+proj=utm +zone=4 +units=km")))
colnames(bathy.df)<-c("x", "y", "z", "x.utm", "y.utm")

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=bathy.df, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z)) +
  geom_contour(binwidth=100)
```

[image: Bathymetry]

```
ggplot(data=bathy.df, aes(x=x.utm, y=y.utm, z=z))+geom_contour(binwidth=100)
Warning messages:
1: `stat_contour()`: Zero contours were generated 
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is that `bathy` is a regular grid in `longlat`, but when you project each point (that represent the center of the grid) onto a different crs (`x.utm, y.utm`) the points change and their current position does not conform a regular grid any more, that is required for `geom_contour()`.
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html

> These functions require regular data, where the x and y coordinates form an equally spaced grid, and each combination of x and y appears once.

My advice is to use `terra` not for projecting points but from convert `bathy` to a SpatRaster grid, and then "project" (or warp) the SpatRaster, that is the correct approach for working with regular grids. Then, as a suggestion (and since you are using `ggplot2`) you can use `tidyterra` to create the plot contours.

The transformation can happen in the plotting phase only (using `coord_sf()`) or creating a new projected SpatRaster (see `bathy_terra_proj`):

See some examples:

```r
library(marmap)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'adehabitatMA':
#>   method                       from
#>   print.SpatialPixelsDataFrame sp  
#>   print.SpatialPixels          sp
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'marmap'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:grDevices':
#> 
#>     as.raster
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.23
library(tidyterra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyterra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggplot2)

bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(
  lon1 = -156.4, lon2 = -156.95,
  lat1 = 20.55, lat2 = 21.05,
  resolution = 1
)
#> Querying NOAA database ...
#> This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size
#> Building bathy matrix ...

# To terra

bathy_terra <- fortify(bathy) %>% rast(crs = "+proj=lonlat")

bathy_terra
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 30, 32, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.01612903, 0.01616379  (x, y)
#> extent      : -156.9081, -156.3919, 20.55754, 21.04246  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        :         z 
#> min value   : -478.0886 
#> max value   : 1519.8207

# Plot with ggplot2

gpl <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_contour(
    data = bathy_terra,
    binwidth = 100
  )

gpl
```

[image]

```r
# With coords utm
gpl +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=utm +zone=4 +units=km") +
  labs(title = "With utm",
       subtitle = "transformation happened in the plot, not in the raster")
```

[image]

```r
# Variatios
## With contours and coords

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_contour_filled(data = bathy_terra, binwidth = 100) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=utm +zone=4 +units=km")
```

[image]

```r
# With labeled contours
# See https://dieghernan.github.io/tidyterra/articles/faqs.html#label-contour
# Need first to project since text contour needs a df

bathy_terra_proj <- bathy_terra %>% project("+proj=utm +zone=4 +units=km")

bathy_terra_proj
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 31, 31, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1.732274, 1.732274  (x, y)
#> extent      : 717.3869, 771.0874, 2275.362, 2329.063  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=4 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        :         z 
#> min value   : -455.5618 
#> max value   : 1285.8115

require("metR")
#> Loading required package: metR
library(metR)

ggplot(bathy_terra_proj) +
  geom_spatraster_contour(data = bathy_terra_proj, binwidth = 100) +
  geom_text_contour(aes(x, y, z = z),
                    binwidth = 100,
                    check_overlap = TRUE, stroke = 0.2,
                    stroke.colour = "white"
  ) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out; posting the answer in case anyone else comes across the same problem. Actually plotting y~x and y.utm~x.utm helped visualize what was going on.

`ggplot(bathy.df, aes(x=x,y=y,color=z))+geom_point()`

[image: x vs y]

`ggplot(bathy.df, aes(x=x.utm,y=y.utm,color=z))+geom_point()`

[image: UTM x vs y]

Basically, they don't line up perfectly. After I rounded the UTM coordinates so that they do, I'm now able to create contours.